# Using HttpListener With Angular's $http.post Instead Of jQuery.Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax, httplistener

To break it down simple - On my Web Application side, I post some data to C# Application that is running a HttpListener, this request is caught by the Listener, then some action is completed, lastly a response is sent back to the Web Application in response to the original post.

Here is the Callback Method that is used once the Listener catches a request

```
private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult listenerresult)
{
    var context = listener.EndGetContext(listenerresult);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    var data_text = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream,
        context.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();

    //Do some work and create the 'responseArray' that is sent back containing some message

    var response = context.Response;
    response.ContentLength64 = responseArray.Length;
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    response.StatusCode = 200;
    response.StatusDescription = "OK";
    response.OutputStream.Write(responseArray, 0, responseArray.Length);
    response.OutputStream.Close();
}
```

When I use a jQuery Ajax Post to reach the Listener and send it some data it works beautifully, and that variable `data_text` is populated with what I sent. Here is the Ajax Post I use:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8089/',
   data: '{"Variable 1":"Value 1", "Variable 2":"Value 2"}',
   crossDomain: true,
   success: function (data) {

      // Use data here

   }
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Alert user that something went wrong');
});
```

I now have to move my implementation over to angular, and this is where the problem comes in. When using Angular's $http.post, the Listner does catch the request however the data_text variable is always empty i.e. the data read from the request's data stream is empty. Here is the $http.post I use - Note: I use a service that wraps the $http.post to save time when using Angular's post:

```
httpService.post('http://127.0.0.1:8089/', data).then(function (result) {
    alert(result.msg);
});
```

And here is the service used to perform the post shown above:

```
app.service('httpService', function($http, $q) {
    this.post = function (url, data) {
        try {
            return $http.post(url, data || {}, { timeout: 1000 * 20 }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    return response.data.obj;
                } else {
                    return ($q.reject(response.data.msg));
                }
            }, function (error) {
                if (error.status === 0) {
                    return ($q.reject('408' + ' : The server timed out waiting for the request, please try again'));
                }
                return ($q.reject(error.status + ' : ' + error.statusText));
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
            return $q.reject(e.message);
        }
    }
});
```

As far as I know, Angular is built ontop of a lite version of jQuery and when you get to the lowest level(vanilla JS), the jQuery Ajax Post is doing the same thing as the $http.post. What am I missing?

**Update**: As [Mike Feltman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528234/mike-feltman) pointed out, I can use $httpParamSerializerJQLike on my data and specify the content type in the header:

```
return $http.post(url,  $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data), { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
```

This works and I receive data, but in a format I can't use, I need my data in JSON format, so I read up a bit and changed the Content-Type from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`, but then I once again receive no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into differences with how Angular sends post data vs. Jquery. To get around this you have to inject $httpParamSerializerJQLike into your service and then specify to use it on your call to http.post by sending your data to a call to it with something like: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData).

This is the angular doc on it:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

I have a working sample that I can't get to at this moment, but can dig it up later if that's not enough to get you going.

I had a few issues in my service getting it to behave and since I also wrap $http I use something like this:

```
var transport = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);
return $http.post(url, transport, { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
```